# Prevent user from navigating to other tab using mat-tab-group, without VIewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular8

I have this mat-tab-group :

```
mat-tab-group
    class="brand-tabs"
    [disableRipple]="true"
    *ngSwitchCase="types.project"
    (selectedTabChange)="changeProjectTab($event)"
    [selectedIndex]="selectedProjectIndex"
>
.........
```

The function in ts :

```
changeProjectTab(event) {
    if (event.index > 0) {
        this.selectedProjectIndex = 0;
        this.modalService.contentModal(
            this.upgradeRef,
            this.translateService.instant('message')
        );
    }
}
```

In this mat-tab-group I have 3 tabs, and I want to stop navigation to tab with index = 1,2, remaining always at tab with index = 0. I tried like this, but not working. Can you give me some ideas please ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable two way binding on `selectedIndex`:

```
<mat-tab-group
    ...
    (selectedTabChange)="changeProjectTab($event)"
    [(selectedIndex)]="selectedProjectIndex"
>
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lkhtgt.

Comment: is working but if I click on second tab, is displayed the tab 2 and quickly pass to the tab 1, is possible to stop this quick move ?

Comment: Maybe - but it would be tricks to hide/show content - maybe something like `<mat-tab label="First"><div [ngStyle]="{'display': selectedProjectIndex === 0 ? 'block' : 'none'}"> Content 1 </div></mat-tab>`. I updated my stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the components/tabs that should not be allowed to navigate?

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples - "Basic use of the tab nav bar" - "disabled link"

Comment: I don't want to disable a tab, I just want to remaining in tab 1, and if user click on tab 2 or 3 show a popup

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding [disabled]='true' to the mat-tab you want to disable? Maybe you can even add a condition: [disabled]='isFirstTab' or something like that.